# Check value on startup and present view controller if value is missing

Tags: ios, swift

On startup, anywhere in the app, I want to be able to check if the logged in user's username is empty or not, and if it is empty, I want to present a view controller where they have to enter a username.

Here is how I'm checking if the user has a username or not:

```
if let user = UserDefaultsUtils().getUser() {
    if (user.username == nil || (user.username != nil && user.username!.isEmpty)) {
        // TODO: Show view controller
    }
}
```

Where would I put this code and how would I present the view controller? App delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Xcode 12

First go to your storyboard. Select the view controllers you want to possibly display to the user on startup and then navigate to the identity inspector panel. Once you're there you will want to set a **unique** storyboard id. This id is what you will be refering to in the code to point to that view controller.
[image: Add a unique id].

Do that for all the controllers you may need to display on startup.

Then you can head over to the SceneDelegate.swift file. We will be writing a bit of code in the **scene** function but first let's see what it does.

```
 var rootViewController : UIViewController
```

This is the controller that will ultimately be displayed to the user. For the moment it is not set.

```
rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "{YOUR_STORYBOARD_FILE_NAME}", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homepage")
```

What this does is it gets a view controller. This is the view controller you want to display if the user previously entered their username. First you get the instance of your current storyboard (that is where the view controller you want to display is). Then from there we instantiate the view controller present inside that storyboard. Here you have to replace the identifier by the one you set.

```
rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "{YOUR_STORYBOARD_FILE_NAME}", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "enterUsername")
```

Again, for the other view controller, the one you want to show if the user didn't already enter its username.

And then we can display the controller as the root one with these three lines :

```
window.rootViewController = rootViewController
self.window = window
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

So now the whole function, while adding your condition :

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene{

        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

        // this is the view controller displayed if the user is already registered
        var rootViewController : UIViewController

        if let user = UserDefaultsUtils().getUser() {
            if (user.username == nil || (user.username != nil && user.username!.isEmpty)) {
                // This is the view controller displayed if the user is already registered.
                rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "{YOUR_STORYBOARD_FILE_NAME}", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "enterUsername")
            }
        } else {
            rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "{YOUR_STORYBOARD_FILE_NAME}", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homepage")
        }


        window.rootViewController = rootViewController
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Now when you start the app it should display the correct view controller.